# jquery ui selectable how to stop selecting inner elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have tried to work out with jquery ui selectable but it is not working as expected. when i selecting list items the inner items are also selecting and i need add a class to selected items.
here is the demo of my stuff.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zZTfA/7/)

```
$(".itemlist").selectable();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the below code in your javascript:

```
$(".itemlist").selectable({ filter: "li" });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: how can add class to selected elements

Comment: See the jQuery docs for a selected event:

http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-selected

Also, the method automatically adds the class 'ui-selected' to selected elements.

Comment: @NicholasE. Thank you. user1834809 Is your problem resolved now? I was in the way to office. I couldn't answer your comment. Sorry about that. Thank you too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".itemlist").selectable({ filter: 'li' });
```